# How to call an iterator as if it was a function

Tags: python

I need a watchdog mecanism to prevent infinite loops. This would look like this:

```
def stop(n):
    """ Returns False after n calls """ 
    for _ in range(n):
        yield True
    yield False
```

and I would use it this way:

```
def foo():
    # this is the function I have to watch
    return True # not good!

while foo() and stop(1000):
    # do some stuff
```

Of course the above code does not work because stop(1000) is an iterator.
I could write a function that mimics stop(), by using a global variable, but it would not be very pythonic. 
I can also write like this:

```
for _ in range(n): 
    if not foo(): 
        break
    # do_some_stuff()
```

It works, but not very elegant, because range(n) is of secondary importance. Is there any Python magic that would make this code elegant?

Comment: Do you need the return value of `foo` in the loop body?

Comment: Appreciate your efforts to make this minimal, but can you give a bit more context on what you are trying to do, I'm struggling to understand your issue

Comment: I second @Chris_Rands comment and would like to ask if my answer is applicable to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instantiate your generator as an object and call `next()`:

```
def stop(n):
    """ Returns False after n calls """ 
    for _ in range(n):
        yield True
    yield False

my_stop = stop(1000)

while not foo() and next(my_stop):
    # do your things
```

This will ensure it keeps going back to the same instance of the generator and stop after 1000 attempts.  Also from what I surmise it seems you meant to break when `foo()` returns `True`? If so the catch should be `not foo()` instead.

Although to be completely Pythonic, I'd argue just use a for loop:

```
# Just realized @timgeb answered the same alternative...
for _ in range(1000):
    if foo():
        break
```

Your `stop()` generator is literally doing the same thing as a for loop, and just returning whether it's still within the for loop.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. Your solution is the closest of what I  was hoping for. I like it because 1/ I can stick to the while loo and, 2/ I can add or remove the watchdog test. Hopefully, it should be removed in the release version of the code.

Answer (score 1):

You could import `islice` from `itertools` and write it like this:

```
for _ in islice(iter(foo, False), n):
    # do stuff
```

This will call `foo` as long as it does not produce `False`, but at most `n` times.

However, personally I like

```
for _ in range(n): 
    if not foo(): 
        break
    # do stuff
```

better. It's two lines longer but more readable.

Comment: Thank you for your time and the idea. I agree that It is better to choose readability rather than a very pythonic oneliner that I would struggle to read in two month.

Answer (score -1):

Just use a counter.

```
count = 0
while not foo():
    count += 1
    if count > 1000:
        break

    # Do things and stuff here
```

Comment: This feels less pythonic than their last attempt

Comment: The good thing in your code is that I can stick to the while loop. The drawback is the need of 4 more lines in the code.